# Node script throws uv_signal_start EINVAL

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and getting started with Node.

I first installed node using the Ubuntu repositories. I ran into some trouble with something, so I re-installed using Chris Lea's repository. After that, node was running better, without that previous error.

Then I ran `sudo npm install node-dev -g`

But running node-dev script.js wasn't working.

```
Error:
node.js:762
          throw errnoException(process._errno, 'uv_signal_start');
                ^
Error: uv_signal_start EINVAL
    at errnoException (node.js:540:13)
    at process.on.process.addListener (node.js:762:17)
    at spawn.cwd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/node-dev:52:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/node-dev:51:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Comment: How was it not working? Any error messages?

Comment: oops, I now added the error to my post

Comment: Which version are you using (node,npm). As of Node.js v0.10.0, the nodejs package from Chris Lea's repo includes both npm and nodejs-dev.

Answer (score 80):

The error isn't with `node-dev`, but rather in your script.  `Error: uv_signal_start EINVAL` is thrown in newer versions of node when you're trying to work with `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`, like so:

```
process.on('SIGKILL', function() { // etc, etc
```

You probably got away with this in earlier versions, but newer versions will now throw this error (see [this GitHub issue for details](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6339)).

Comment: TIL on Windows it just doesn't register the event, while it completely crashes on Linux. Thank you, I woul've never guessed that